# Misunderstanding of philosopher work by other philosopher in ancient time

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Throughout history, we have had many philosophers pre-Socrates to  Aristotle to Morden Era,
Did in ancient times around 1 B.C.E to 5 A.D, be it, philosophers or Astronomers when quoting famous philosophers' works, in their work for E.g: 1 A.D astronomers may quote or use Aristotle work, but write get it wrong like Aristotle said Earth is centre of cosmos were 1 A.D writer, writes that Arisitotle said that Sun is Centre of Cosmos, not Earth. Is there any example like this in the work of Ancient times?